# Excel: Dynamic SUM with OFFSET calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, powerbi, vba

I need to create a dynamic sum of data chunks out of a large data set contained in a csv file (>100k rows). The data is planned to be displayed in PowerBI but I have literately no idea of the DAX coding language or VBA. So I hope I can preformat the data in excel.

The way to distinguish the data sub-sets I want to sum up is a counting row. The rows starts with every new subset from 1 but the final number >= 1 is totally ‘random’.

The first row is the countingRow the second row is the dataRow.

```
> 1    45 
  2    20
  3    20 
  4    10   -> SUM 95 
> 1    30 
  2     5   -> SUM 35 
> 1     X   -> new SUM
```

I think it is possible to work with the **SUM, IF** and  **OFFSET** function. 
My plan was to check whether a cell contains a 1 or not. Check the range between two true values minus one cell, then calculate the offset sum in the other column. 
But when I thought I found the solution I realized that I have no way to bring my pointer to a new data subset.

Which function do I need to move my calculation threw the column?

Is it even possible to do an calculation of this scale in excel?

PS: I'm although thankful for a DAX or VBA tutorial which could bring me to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly shorter formula without array type formula:

```
=IF(OR(A3={1,""}),SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the following sample data image, use the following formula in D2.

```
=IF(OR(A3={1,""}), SUM(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:2)/(A$1:A2=1), 1)):INDEX(B:B, ROW())), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down.

[image]